# Image is not centered

Tags: css

In my footer area I have set a background image. Problem is it is not centered. Only the some part of image is shown. Right end of the image is hidden. If I crop the image, I can handle this. But I want to handle it from css.

Here is the code

```
#footer{

}

#middle-footer{
    background-image:url('img/footer-bg.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:inherit;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="footer" style="height:200px;">
    <div id="middle-footer" >
    </div>
 </div>
```

How to do this?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't just whitespace on the left side of the image?

Comment: What is the width of the `footer-bg.gif`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `overflow: hidden` property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this. Instead of using `background-image:` use the short-hand and after the URL use `top center`. Code will be:

```
#footer {
    background: url('img url') top center;
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are adding your backgrond through css. So, for position the background image, you have to use background-position: property, but I did it shortcut way.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the background in CSS is possible only with modern browsers. So, if you would like to do, add this:

```
background-size: 90%;
```

The full CSS is:

```
#middle-footer{
    background-image:url('img/footer-bg.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 90%;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:inherit;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mixing a `width: 100%` with the centering trick of doing `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` which won't work since if the width is 100% then the margins will be `auto`matically nothing since the box fills the space.  So I reworked the CSS so it has a fixed width.  I also added a color to the box since we don’t have an image to look at for reference but need to see the box. I also moved the inline style for `#footer` into the CSS since it was weird to see that empty `#footer { }` in the CSS.  Here is a full HTML example of how it should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>CSS Centering Fixed</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        #footer
        {
            height: 200px;
        }

        #middle-footer
        {
        display: block;
            background-image: url('img/footer-bg.gif');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: #ffffcc;
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            height: inherit;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="middle-footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not remove width:100% proerty as footer area should be fully covered in every screen sizes. actually it is useless to use margin-left, right: auto property here. however here is an accepted answere below. thanks